# How to Deserialize json Object on gridview?

Tags: c#, .net, json, visual-studio

I am building C# windows form that accessing json data. I want to make it display on gridview.

How can I `DeserializeObject` the json data on gridview?
Sorry for newbie here.

```
   public class Namedata
    {
        public string PeopleName { get; set; }
        public string PeopleAge { get; set; }
        public string PeopleSurname { get; set; }
    }
    
    public class SName
    {
        public int ResultCode { get; set; }
        public string ResultName { get; set; }
        public IList<Namedata> namedatas { get; set; }
    }
    
    public class Example
    {
        public SName s_name { get; set; }
    }

  public void GETJsondata()
            {
    string username = "myuser"; 
     string password = "myuserpass";                 
     byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("{\"name\":\"" + Name.Text + "\",\"id\":\"1\"}");               
     WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://myservice/Service4.svc/s_name");                
     request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1").GetBytes(username + ":" + password)));
     request.Method = "POST";
     request.ContentType = "application/json";
     request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
     Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream();
     stream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
     stream = request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream();
     var result = (new StreamReader(stream).ReadLine());             
    
    JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Example>(result); 
    
     ultragridiew1.DataSource = result;
    }
```

here are json data:

```
{
    "s_name": {
        "ResultCode": 1,
        "ResultName": "Found",
        "namedatas": [
            {              
                "PeopleName": "Jane",
                "PeopleAge": "20",
                "PeopleSurname": "Jade"

            },
                  {              
                "PeopleName": "Newton",
                "PeopleAge": "18",
                "PeopleSurname": "Handy"

            },
                  {              
                "PeopleName": "Java",
                "PeopleAge": "21",
                "PeopleSurname": "Handy"

            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: You have written some code? What's the issue you are facing with that?

Comment: No data on gridview.

Comment: result is a string variable... you are assigning string to GridView... that's why you don't see data in grid view... You need to create object of class as a result of deserialization...  `var exampleObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Example>(result);`... what data from Example class you want to bind to the GridView?

Comment: I want to bind "Namedata". See above  "here are json data:"

Comment: `ultragridiew1.DataSource = exampleObj.s_name.namedatas`

Comment: @Chetan Ranpariya  Thank you for anwsering me. That was correct. I want to accept your answer is correct but you didn't replied just commented

Comment: @J.Col, I am glad to hear that your problem has been solved, you can click '✔' to mark the appropriate reply as an answer so that others can solve the problem if they face the similar problem.

Comment: But he didn't write as answer

Comment: @J.Col, you can also make a reply yourself and mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Chetan Ranpariya had correct me. Thank you

```
   public class Namedata
    {
        public string PeopleName { get; set; }
        public string PeopleAge { get; set; }
        public string PeopleSurname { get; set; }
    }
    
    public class SName
    {
        public int ResultCode { get; set; }
        public string ResultName { get; set; }
        public IList<Namedata> namedatas { get; set; }
    }
    
    public class Example
    {
        public SName s_name { get; set; }
    }

  public void GETJsondata()
            {
    string username = "myuser"; 
     string password = "myuserpass";                 
     byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("{\"name\":\"" + Name.Text + "\",\"id\":\"1\"}");               
     WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://myservice/Service4.svc/s_name");                
     request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1").GetBytes(username + ":" + password)));
     request.Method = "POST";
     request.ContentType = "application/json";
     request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
     Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream();
     stream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
     stream = request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream();
     var result = (new StreamReader(stream).ReadLine());             
    
    var exampleObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Example>(result);
    
     ultragridiew1.DataSource = exampleObj.s_name.namedatas
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not giving the gridview the correct source. Try this,

```
var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Example>(result);
ultragridiew1.DataSource = data.s_name.namedatas;
```

Answer (score 0):

Base on the information, here is a potential solution:

`public class Namedata
    {
        public string PeopleName { get; set; }
        public string PeopleAge { get; set; }
        public string PeopleSurname { get; set; }
    }

    public class SName
    {
        public int ResultCode { get; set; }
        public string ResultName { get; set; }
        public Namedata[] namedatas { get; set; }
    }

    public class Example
    {
        public SName s_name { get; set; }
    }

     public void GETJsondata()
            {
                HttpClient _client = new HttpClient();
                string username = "myuser";
                string password = "myuserpass";
                var byteArray = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes($"{username}:{password}");
                _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray));
    
                dynamic content = new ExpandoObject();
                content.name = Name.Text;
                content.id = 1;
    
                var json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(content);
    
                var data = new StringContent(json, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
               
                var response = _client.PostAsync("http://myservice/Service4.svc/s_name", data).Result;
                var result = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Example>(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
    
            ultragridiew1.DataSource = data.s_name.namedatas;
    
            }`

Main change I have done is to use HttpClient. It removes a lot of boilerplate code that is required with webrequest.

Comment: Is that decrease execution time?

Comment: Worst case it would be same as what you are doing :)
There are other advantages as well as it avoids potential memory/connection leaks. In future, if you decide to make your application async, this would help tremendously. Currently, I have converted async methods to sync methods because I don't have the know-how of your solution.